# Getting page expired error in laravel when running curl

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using curl for making laravel API.
When I send post request through curl it shows me error "page has expired due to inactivity" and when I except token route it runs properly.
But I want to use csrf token how to make it.

```
Curl -H "X-CSRF-TOKEN : token" -X POST  -d '{data}' http://local host:8000/api
```

I used these curl command to run the request.

Comment: are you using api route?? show route url that you are calling using curl.

Comment: No I&amp;#39;m using web route

Route::post('api','controllee@method');

Comment: not this one, the one that you are calling using curl??

Comment: Route::post('api','controller@method');

Comment: is it in web routes??

Comment: Yes it is in web route

Comment: show us `config/session.php` this file

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not use csrf protection when connecting through API calls.
[Laravel exclude csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

So, just exclude your routes in the `VerifyCsrfToken` class.